# How to bind XML to Java code with validation?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xsd-validation

It may seems that this issue is so common that it should be resolved, but after few hours of searching I wasn not been able to find a solution besides to write my own binder througth Java Reflection API. It would be nice if there would be some library that can bind XML to Java classes and do a validation with XSD file (with default values, etc.)

Any tips?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question, but, I think **jaxb2** is exactly what you are looking for, Am i wrong?

Comment: I guess that is it. I only guess because it is too cumbersome to understand it when you see it for the first time :)